# Why my views are overlapping status bar in Android Studio Layout Editor

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio-3.0

For some time now, all the layouts I make look like this in the Layout Editor. I do not remember if this was normal before, but this is kind of annoying.

[image]

As you can see, the ImageView and the TextView are over the status bar. 
And even worse ListView is on top of both, even though I've set:

```
android:layout_below="@id/txt_title"
```

The final result of view is as I expected:

```
[Imageview][TextView]
[ List View         ]
```

But this bug (?) in the editor is annoying me.

This is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/primary"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    >


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_logo"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:ico_color="@color/iconColor"
        app:ico_icon="cmd-download"
        app:ico_size="24dp"

        />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/img_logo"
        android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
        android:paddingEnd="8dp"
        android:paddingStart="8dp"
        android:text="@string/title_favorite_beers"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="15sp"


        />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/widget_list_collection"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/txt_title"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:padding="8dp"

        />


</RelativeLayout>
```

-- EDIT --
I have changed the layout to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:background="@color/primary"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    >


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/widget_image_logo"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@color/iconColor"
        android:foreground="?android:selectableItemBackground"
        android:foregroundGravity="center_vertical"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_beer_launch"
        />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/widget_image_logo"
        android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
        android:paddingEnd="8dp"
        android:paddingStart="8dp"
        android:text="@string/title_favorite_beers"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        tools:text="Favorite Beers"


        />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/widget_list_collection"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/txt_title"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:padding="8dp"

        />


</RelativeLayout>
```

The result is:

[image]

my styles.xml:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/window_background</item>
        <item name="android:dialogTheme">@style/TitledDialog</item>
    </style>

    <style name="TitledDialog" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.PrimaryButton" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button">
        <item name="android:layout_height">@dimen/button_height</item>
        <item name="android:padding">@dimen/button_padding</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:background">?attr/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:foreground">?attr/selectableItemBackground</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.Toolbar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

    <style name="CollapsedToolbar" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ExpandedToolbar" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>

    <string name="movie_details">Movie Details</string>
</resources>
```

-- EDIT --

Editor is overlaping the status bar in all the views from this project. As you can see in this activity that uses CoordinatorLayout in root:

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layout_search"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.github.alexpfx.udacity.beercollection.search.SearchActivity"
    >

    <include layout="@layout/layout_toolbar"/>

    <include layout="@layout/content_search_activity"/>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Why are you even looking at the layout tool?  Its a piece of junk.  Write your layouts in xml, learn how to visualize it, and then test by running on an actual device.  All the visual layout tool will do is slow you down and confuse things.

Comment: I do not know ... I've always done it. It works well to view something quickly, without having to run the entire program. And for ConstraintLayouts it even helps. But then this bug is normal?

Comment: Can you post your full xml for the layout?

Comment: @Naveed Yes, sorry, I forgot.

Comment: @GabeSechan “why are you even looking at the layout tool” -> The layout tool is not the best and may not be as responsive as Interface Builder in Xcode, but it’s still a very valid tool and it works more often than not. Sometimes it requires a close/reopen or it has problems with some layouts, but for the most part, it’s a very fast way to determine if what you’re manually writing in XML, makes sense. Especially if/when using ConstraintLayouts, where the engine must calculate the widget position based upon an algorithm.

Comment: @MartinMarconcini I disagree-  its a horrible tool that's slower to use, less powerful, and frequently actively harmful.  It should never be used.  If you do use it, you're relying on an inaccurate crutch that's actively hindering your ability to do things well long term.  It ought to be nuked from orbit, not encouraged.

Comment: @GabeSechan fine, if you don’t want to use it, that’s perfectly acceptable, but please try not to spread falsehoods with your own opinions. I know a lot of developers (myself included) who use the tool on a daily basis with a moderate degree of success; it’s a matter of knowing when to use it and when not to rely on it. I insist, the visual editor in android is not perfect, but gets the job done more often than not, *especially for quick previews*

Comment: @MartinMarconcini I'm not spreading falsehoods.  Its a piece of absolute shit that's rarely accurate, slow, and hinders real understanding of the xml layout language.  You're doing a HUGE disservice to all developers by suggesting someone ever use it.  And to yourself by not learning how to do things without it and using it as a crutch (especially since half the time its still just wrong).

Comment: @GabeSechan sure, continue with your prejudices, spreading lies (just because you don’t like it doesn’t mean other people has to dislike it too), and your inability to find a way to incorporate the tool. I’m sure a lot of other developers consider your advice a HUGE disservice, not sure about the “all” part, but ohh well. Also suggesting “I need to learn how to do things without it”… is very nice of you. Get better at being a human being and get better at being humble. o/

Comment: @MartinMarconcini This is me being humble.  You couldn't take me at full awesomeness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few issues I see with your layout

1. The [ImageView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html) class does not have attributes for:

   **Update**: As per comment, the following attributes are fine since the op is using [Android-Iconics](https://github.com/mikepenz/Android-Iconics)

   `app:ico_color="@color/iconColor"
     app:ico_icon="cmd-download"
     app:ico_size="24dp"`
2. You are constraining the list view to be under your text view but based on the image you posted, it seems like that your text view has no content so it is overlapping with your image view.  You can fix this by constraining it under the view with the greater height e.g. your image view has the larger height in your posted example.

It seems like you want something along the lines of:

[Imageview][TextView]

[ List View         ]

I have modified your code to the following which should provide the desired results.

Note: that I have changed some of the values(such as color, background, text etc), you'll need to add them accordingly.

Lastly, ensure that your theme is not responsible for causing the layout to overlap with status bar.  Also the layout editor has improved over the android studio releases.  Make sure you have the latest version of android studio.  The below image is from Android Studio 3.0.1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/red"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
>


    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_logo"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@color/red"
            android:src="@android:drawable/stat_sys_download"
    />


    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/img_logo"
            android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
            android:paddingEnd="8dp"
            android:paddingStart="8dp"
            android:text="test"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="15sp"


    />

    <ListView
            android:id="@+id/widget_list_collection"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/img_logo"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:padding="8dp"

    />


</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. The attributes are from Android-Iconics, but I remove it since it doesn't work by default in layouts for widgets. I replaced ImageView for ImageButton. The text view has the content: "Favorite beers", I put it in tools:text to show it in editor. My Android Studio is 3.0.1 too. I almost sure there is a problem with the theme as you said. I edit my first question with modifications you suggest and others I made. In the App it shows the layout exactly as I want, but in editor it is still weird.